# Cannot copy "fileobj" Name from loop into spreadsheet range

Tags: excel, range, filenames

I set up a file object of files on a USB stick and wish to copy their names to an excel range in a worksheet, it works till you try and save the fileObj.Name to a range.

Most of the code was from this gentlemans excellent answer to this question 5 years ago "trouble with code to read multiple files in loop to read and special lines to import" he supplied two excellent answers; and it mostly works, except type mismatch or object not set error depending on what you change around.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Test1()

      Dim FileSysObj As Object
      Dim FolderObj As Object
      Dim FileColl As Object
      Dim FileObj As Object
      Dim s, fc, f1, CurrFile, cfile
      Dim PathSearch As String
      Dim FinalRow As Range


      ' This assumes the text files are in the same folder as the workbook holding the macro.
      ' Use PathSearch = "C:\ ..." if you would rather have the files in a different folder.
      PathSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Path

      Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.getfolder(PathSearch)
      Set FileColl = FolderObj.subfolders


     ' For Each FileObj In FileColl


           ' Set CurrFile = FileObj.Files

          '  For Each cfile In CurrFile
           '  s = s & cfile.Name

       '    ***FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row.Value***

    ' Ans = FinalRow.Value = s
     "Here is the solution code

           For Each FileObj In FileColl


        Set currfile = FileObj.Files

        For Each cfile In currfile
         i = i + 1
         f = cfile.Name

      'Now deal with your worksheets

        Cells(i, 1).Value = f


      Next

  Next

End Sub





I have added the solution. below was the problem, no one replied.
```

I get either a type mismatch error or a set or with not set for object error, I wish to get the filenames on the folders in the USB on the spreadsheet, to keep a database of the contents of my USB's.

Comment: Please share with us the specific line and its specific error message.  Or two lines and their two messages.  otherwise we are in the dark.

Comment: References to properties and methods often require an explicit object qualifier. This error has the following causes and solutions: Error 424 the code highlighted with the three asterix.

Comment: When the the currfile and s variable are tracked in the immediate window the program cycles through fiolders and names each file, however my confused attempts at transfering the filenames from variable s to a spreadsheet range in a worksheet called 'dataOutput' fails.

Comment: The type mismatch occurs when I try and fix the first error, I am obviously setting or not setting an object. If I add CurrentRegion("A1") or  Worksheet(dataOutput), neither helps.

Comment: Please supply the url of "trouble with code to read multiple files in loop to read and special lines to import"  so that I can read his original code.  Or paste his original code below your code.

Comment: I solved my own problem here is the solution

Comment: Here is the solution I figured it out for reference for anyone interested